# PHP SimpleXMLElement problems with xml node

Tags: php, xml

I want to create an XML with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
    <!-- content goes here -->
</content>
```

I originally created the xml node like this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
$content = $xml->addChild('content');
// add data to content
```

but that doesn't allow for adding attributes to the xml node, so now I do this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
                      .'<content></content>');
```

For some reason it doesn't work without adding the content node, but whatever, it gets the structure right.

Now, **how do I assign the content node to a variable** like I did above, so I can add data to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the $xml variable is equal to the content node just try the following:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
    .'<content></content>');
$xml->addAttribute('Attribute', 'value');
$xml->addChild('node_name', 'value');
echo $xml->asXML();
```

this should print

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content Attribute="value"><node_name>value</node_name></content>
```

Answer (score 1):

E.g.

```
<?php
$content = new SimpleXMLElement('<content />');
$content['attr']='value';

echo $content->asXML();
```

prints

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<content attr="value"/>
```

--- edit:
To keep the encoding=utf-8:

```
$content = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content />');
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I assign the content node to a variable to actually work with it when I do it like that?

Comment: xml version 1.0 default encoding is UTF-8, so there is no need to "keep" it :)

Answer (score 1):

An XML document must have at least one element. That is the document element. In your question this is the *content* element.

You can create a **SimpleXMLElement** of it by just instantiating it with this minimum string:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<content/>');
```

The variable `$xml` then represents that element. You can then...

- ... add attributes: `$xml['attribute'] = 'value';`
- ... set the content-text: `$xml[0] = 'text';`
- ... add child-elements: `$xml->child = 'value';`

This exemplary line-up then would have created the following XML (beautified, also: [online demo](https://eval.in/418392)):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<content attribute="value">
  text
  <child>value</child>
</content>
```